# puppet master not signing certificate

Tags: certificate, puppet

I am using puppet with cobbler and I am having a problem with certificate signing. I have configured so that cobbler will revoke the puppet client certificate when a puppet managed machine is reinstalled. The revoking part runs just fine and puppetmaster listed out a the new client certificate, but puppetmaster failed to sign it, thus puppet client failed to run.

This is the output when I listed all the certificates on puppet master:

```
# puppet cert list -a
+ "spacewalk"               (SHA256) E3:63:F1:9A:10:1E:AD:20:72:DA:17:0E:0F:EB:F5:2B:9E:7E:26:80:8D:58:2E:28:A2:2D:68:01:F7:BD:A8:B3 (alt names: "DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppet.playground.local", "DNS:spacewalk")
- "p1.playground.local" (SHA256) CD:AD:3E:04:04:C0:84:88:A0:67:F7:56:57:F1:67:82:43:31:CE:37:71:10:01:AD:15:DE:5A:0E:2E:7C:63:DE (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

This is the error when I ran `puppet agent -t` on puppet client:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed warning: Not using cache on failed catalog err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

This is the error when I try to get the master to sign the certificate:

```
# puppet cert sign p1.playground.local
Error: Could not find certificate request for p1.playground.local
```

This is the error after running puppet agent -t, upon revoking the certificate:

```
# puppet agent -t 
info: Creating a new SSL key for p1.playground.local warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
info: Caching certificate for ca 
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session 
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session 
info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for p1.playground.local 
info: Certificate Request fingerprint (md5): 65:F0:6D:8D:66:89:57:13:11:A6:DD:02:DF:DC:C1:7B warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session 
err: Could not request certificate: Could not intern from s: nested asn1 error Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

I removed the /var/lib/puppet/ssl directory at the client, rerun `puppet agent -t` and I got the same error as above.

Finally I tried to remove the /var/lib/puppet/ssl directory on both master and client, regenerate the certificates and all is good. Even though I can just remove the ssl directory everytime before I start with the auto installation, but it would be great if I don't have to do it manually.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Missed the version. Master runs 3.7.4-1 and client 2.6.12-0.10.1.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You must `revoke` the client cert on the master and also `clean` it to make way for a new cert for the same name.  Then the agent on the rebuilt system must issue a certificate-signing request (which it will do on its first run) before there is anything for the master to sign.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Inside the kickstart I added a script that will revoke the certificate. It used to work. Sorry, in my post I should've said that I revoked and cleaned the certificate, and not just revoking it. The master puppet then added the client certificate, but did not sign it, which cause the puppet on client failed to run. That is when I tried to remove the `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` directory on both master and client, and it worked. I prefer not to do this manually.

Comment: @FelixFrank My question is how to fix the problem where I have to manually remove the `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` directory on the master everytime a new system is installed and generates a new certificate. I want puppet on client to run automatically when the operating system installation is completed.

Comment: I see. Well that *is* supposed to Just Work. Your master setup is broken in some way. Can you paste the output of `puppet master --configprint all` somewhere?

Comment: @FelixFrank Hmm.. I don't know what happened, but it worked now (just how you said it should). I have the output of configprint anyway, just in case if there's anything to see. Thanks much.
http://pastebin.com/TxFwhX5e

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Voting to close; please make sure your issues are reproducible before asking for help.